# JavaScript - Formating a long integer

Tags: javascript, string, integer

How can I take a JavaScript integer of arbitrary length, such as `1234567890`, and format it as a string "1,234,567,890"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use toLocaleString() for the format that you have asked.

```
var myNum = 1234567890;
var formattedNum = myNum.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Good point, but [browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
var number = 1234567890;
var str = number + "";
var result = str.split('').map(function (a, i) { 
    if ((i - str.length) % 3 === 0 && i !== 0) { 
        return ',' + a;
    } else { 
        return a;
    } 
}).join('');
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4492fge/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably with a regular expression. From [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript):

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: If an existing answer solves a question, it should be marked as duplicate.